# Existence of annihilating polynomial that is not characteristic

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix, is it always true that there exists a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ such that $f(A)=0$ but $f$ is not the characteristic polynomial of $A$? Are there situations where we can infer such  polynomial is the characteristic polynomial?

For example, if $A$ is the zero matrix, then $x^n+x$ satisfies the conditions but is not the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Well, in a field with characteristic other than $2$, you can multiply the characteristic polynomial by a scalar other than $0$ or $1$ to obtain another polynomial annihilating $A$. But that's a bit trivial...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the case iff the minimal polynomial $\mu_A$ of $A$ has degree $<n$.

- If $\deg \mu_A<n$, then $f=\chi_A+\mu_A$ has the desired properties $f(A)=0$ and $\deg f=n$.
- And vice versa, if $f$ is any polynomial of degree $n$ with $f(A)=0$ and leading coefficient 1, then $\chi_A-f$ has degree $<n$ so that necessarily $\deg \mu_A\le \deg(\chi_A-f)<n$.

Comment: Perhaps a product $\mu_A\cdot q$ would be a bit better example than the sum (in the sense of the general structure of an annihilating polynomial).

Answer (score 0):

If the minimal polynomial has less degree than the characteristic polynomial, then it's of course true, else any scaler multiplied by the characteristic polynomial would satisfy but if you want a monic polynomial then it won't work.

Note that if the characteristic polynomial has $n$ distinct roots then a monic polynomial of degree less than that of the characteristic polynomial, that satisfies $A$, doesn't exist!